# Devexpress WinForms PivotGrid cell color depending on Field

Tags: winforms, devexpress, pivot, pivot-grid

In WinForms DevExpress (16.1) I have a PivotGrid Control and a CustomCellValue event handler, I was wondering if it is possible to set the cell style along with the value in the same handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom "Appearance" can be managed through the `CustomAppearance` event handlers.